# Form submission leaving out a value

Tags: php, javascript, forms, google-chrome, submit

The value of my `submit` button is being lost if submitted via javascript in Chrome v19. It works in IE8, IE9 and FF12. I have the following page that exhibits the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitorder()
    {
        document.openord.TYPE.value='Submitted using javascript';
        document.openord.submit();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<pre>
The contents of $_REQUEST are:
<?php var_dump($_REQUEST); ?>
</pre>

<form method="post" action="showParms.php" name="openord">
    <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="Submitted the regular ol' way">
    <input type="hidden" name="NAME" value="Frederick Q. Larson">
    <input type="submit" name="TASK" value="Submit with Javascript" onclick='submitorder();'>
    <input type="submit" name="TASK" value="Normal Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Click the "Normal Submit" and you'll see a value for `TASK` like this:

```
The contents of $_REQUEST are:
array(3) {
  ["TYPE"]=>
  string(29) "Submitted the regular ol' way"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(19) "Frederick Q. Larson"
  ["TASK"]=>
  string(13) "Normal Submit"
}
```

Not so with the "Submit with Javascript" button:

```
The contents of $_REQUEST are:
array(2) {
  ["TYPE"]=>
  string(26) "Submitted using javascript"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(19) "Frederick Q. Larson"
}
```

In IE and FF, when clicking "Submit with Javascript" you see:

```
The contents of $_REQUEST are:
array(3) {
  ["TYPE"]=>
  string(26) "Submitted using javascript"
  ["NAME"]=>
  string(19) "Frederick Q. Larson"
  ["TASK"]=>
  string(22) "Submit with Javascript"
}
```

Any idea why Chrome is having a problem with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to submit the form with a parameter changed through JavaScript, then

```
function submitorder() {
    document.openord.TYPE.value='Submitted using javascript';
}
```

is sufficient, because the form will automatically be submitted when the user clicks on the submit button.

### "Correct" behaviour

According to the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/form-submission.html#constructing-form-data-set), section "4.10.22.4 Constructing the form data set":

> The algorithm to construct the form data set for a form *form* optionally in the context of a submitter *submitter* is as follows. If not specified otherwise, *submitter* is null.
>   `. . .`
>   3. *Loop*: For each element field in controls, in tree order, run the following substeps:
>        1. If any of the following conditions are met, then skip these substeps for this element:
>       `. . .`
>       •    The field element is a button but it is not submitter.

This algorithm is used when a form is submitted ([specification reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/form-submission.html#submit-body)).
Apparently, since no button was clicked, the *submitter* is empty, hence no submit element.

In Firefox, the button which initiates the function which submits the form seems to be flagged *submitter*. Calling the function without a (form submit) button shows the same behaviour as in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/3fwcr/1/.

When `event.preventDefault();` is added to the button's `click` event, then the form also submits as in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/3fwcr/2/.
Apparently, Firefox' default submission is still triggered, even though the form is already being submitted (seems to be against the specification: "If form is already being submitted (..), then abort these steps" ("these steps" = form submission)).

Comment: Thanks much. Good references.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a problem/bug, it's just because you are using JavaScript for submitting. You could add some code like this:

```
var hiddenVal = document.createChild("input");
hiddenVal.setProperty("name", "TASK");
hiddenVal.setProperty("type", "hidden");
hiddenVal.setProperty("value", Submit with JavaScript");
document.openord.appendChild(hiddenVal);
```

Comment: I thought so at first, but then IE and FF do it right. Just wondering why Chrome is having difficulty. Or is everyone else doing it wrong and Chrome is right?

Comment: Good question... But I think it's actually correct or at least "more correct" how IE and FF do.